# javascript / react - switching the properties of two objects in an array in react state without triggering a re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, konvajs, react-konva

I just need to replace one array object's keys with another. I'll provide a rationale for why I *think I need to do this afterward to try and avoid the TLDR, in case someone spots a deeper reason why I might not need to do this at all.

So given:

```
canvasImages = [
  {
    property1: 1
    property2: 2
  },
  {
    property1: 3,
    property2: 4,
  }
]
```

I want to specify two objects in the array and loop through their properties (because the list of properties could be long), and say (pseudocode):

```
canvasImages[1].property1 = canvasImages[2].property1;
canvasImages[2].property2 = canvasImages[2].property2;
etc...
```

in as minimal code as possible.

RATIONALE:

I am using react with a canvas library where two draggable canvas objects 
from an array in state need to switch z order without triggering a re-render from react (otherwise the canvas loses the memory of where the objects were dragged...).

So when I tried to simply do:

```
const {canvasImages} = this.state;
const oldIndex = 1; const newIndex = 2;
const reorderedCanvasImages = reorderArray(canvasImages,oldIndex,newIndex) //unshown function, just reorders the array
this.setState({
  canvasImages: reorderedCanvasImages //this triggers a re-mount of the URLImage component
});
```

or:

```
const newCanvasImages = _.clonedeep(canvasImages);
const oldIndex = 1; const newIndex = 2;
const reorderedCanvasImages = reorderArray(canvasImages,oldIndex,newIndex) 
this.state.canvasImage[0] = newCanvasImages[0];
this.state.canvasImage[1] = newCanvasImages[1];
```

those canvasImages lose any dragged position:

```
canvasImages.map((canvasImage, index) => {
//remounted after setState on canvasImages or even after changing array positions within this.state.canvasImages
return (
  <URLImage
    src={`${canvasImage.image}`}
    isInteractable={activeCanvasImageIndex === index}
    className={`canvas__interactable`}
    key={`canvas__interactable--${canvasImage.object}_${index}`}
  />
)
```

Comment: When wrapping third-party library within a React component, it's often needed to prevent the update with [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and let the third-party code update itself.

Comment: Well - it does need to update, things like the "isInteractable prop" are driven from the parent. But I'm also saying that the whole component re-mounts, because the array that renders each item changes. I think that is what re-sets the positions.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` let's you filter what should update or not. Also, when the third-party has a single instance that shouldn't be reinitialized at all, you should handle the update manually, passing down new values to the third-party instance through their API.

Comment: I say "third-party", but it could be your own canvas, an iframe, etc. You're not required to use React for the update, it's just best practices to keep manual updates to a minimum.

Comment: Yeah - wondering if I should use the non-react version of the library so I have access to the z-index property rather than having to change the array around...that's really all I need to do.

Comment: Make sure you are using `key` attribute properly. it is better to use some kind of `id` for `canvasImage` to set a key. Using `index` inside the key is a bad approach. That is why it is remounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you are using `index` and an object inside the key attribute:

```
key={`canvas__interactable--${canvasImage.object}_${index}`}
```

When you reorder objects, you will have completely NEW keys, that different from the old ones. In that case, React thinks it is new components, so it removes old ones and creates new. To avoid it just use uniq `id` for each item in the array:

```
const canvasImages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    property1: 1
    property2: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    property1: 3,
    property2: 4,
  }
]

canvasImages.map((canvasImage, index) => {
return (
  <URLImage
    src={`${canvasImage.image}`}
    isInteractable={activeCanvasImageIndex === index}
    className={`canvas__interactable`}
    key={canvasImage.id}
  />
)
```